# JSONP post request in angularJs

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, jsonp

I would like to do this post call using jsonp in angularJs.

```
JQ.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(error) {}
});
```

Somebody can help me to do this?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: See my answer below. Any question? If so, just ask. If it solved your problem feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

**You could use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**

Example:

```
$http({method: 'JSONP', url: "http://something.com/path?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"}).
success(function(data, status) {
 //access data here
}).error(function(data, status) {
 console.log(data || "Request failed");
});
```

You have to change the url parameter to whatever url you are going to use ofcourse, but notice that you have to include the part with "callback=JSON_CALLBACK". You should check out [this link](http://jaketrent.com/post/make-jsonp-requests-with-angularjs/) for more information.

Comment: I wrote the url in this way : 'http://.....?data='+params+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'